# Sentence pattern

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> She was obedient to her elders.

In this sentence, how do you label the phrase "to her elders?" The subject of this sentence is 'She', the verb is 'was'. complement is 'obedient', what is to her elders'?

Comment: The PP "to her elders" is Complement of the adjective "obedient". The AdjP "obedient to her elders" then functions as predicative complement of "be" in its ascriptive sense.

Comment: @BillJ the prepositional phrase *to her elders* qualifies the adjective *obedient*, doesn't it? Then, isn't its function adverbial?

Comment: No, it's a complement because it is licensed (specifically permitted or required) by "obedient".

Answer (score 1):

In a comment BillJ wrote:

> The PP "to her elders" is Complement of the adjective "obedient". The AdjP "obedient to her elders" then functions as predicative complement of "be" in its ascriptive sense.

Comment: To her elders, she was obedient. in other words," She obeys her elders".

Comment: Heh. I've been dabbling in this exchange for some months now. This may be the most technical answer I've seen yet. Definitely +1.

Comment: A definite +1 would require an attributed linked reference. This is probably from CGEL, which has possibly the best definition of 'complement', but not the monopoly on accepted terminology.